# Space between block color glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Why am I getting those weird glitches and how can I stop it? I've never had them before 1.5.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the 1.5.1 [patch release notes](http://mojang.com/2013/03/minecraft-1-5-1-pre-release/):

- Notable: White stitching between blocks should be less frequent

So presumably, the answer is to wait a few days for that to be released (or snag the prerelease, up now, if you feel brave)